# how to convert MS word Unicode 2-byte Cyrillic to CP866 1-byte Cyrillic

Tags: utf

I am having an issue with a piece of hardware that only contains the CP866 library/code page for Cyrillic. The text that I want to display is currently in MS Word and I need to convert it to the CP866 in a text file. (I know it just keeps getting worse!)

I am aware that MS Word uses Unicode to display Cyrillic and if i am not mistaken it uses the UTF-16. So if I try to copy it to NP++, which from what I can tell only uses UTF-8, the HEX value changes.

For example HEX values for 'й':  UTF-16 is 0439 but UTF-8 is d0b9 but what I need is CP866 HEX 89.

Now I wish I could use different hardware, but it is what it is. Does anyone know the best way to make this happen? Maybe a different Text Editor someone could suggest.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

Open the .doc file, go to Word Options under the main round office button. Advanced tab -> General tab -> check Confirm file format conversion on open. click ok. close that file

Reopen the .doc file. Save as, change type to Plan text (.txt), file conversion should pop up. choose Cyrillic (DOS). click OK. new pop-up about something might not display, blah blah blah... click Yes.

Close the file.

go to the file and open it in NP++. everything looks all strange because its now displaying the format based on the ANSI map... BUT, the HEX values seem (I have not completely verified) to be the correct CP866. Now I can load my hardware.

I will be working on this for another day or two. I will report back if this did not work correctly.

Take a day off and come back later. It always seems to work. Hope this helps out anyone else who maybe experiencing Similar issues.

Best!